# Spring @Async annotation on interface methods

Tags: multithreading, spring

Can the Spring `@Async` annotation be used on interface methods (so all implementations of that interface will implicitly have `@Async` on that method) or can it only be used on concrete classes?

Comment: I tried annotating an interface method (and it compiled), but would rather find out whether it would actually work before starting to implement the concrete classes

Comment: In case you use cglib proxy instead of jdk proxy, and annotate with @Async on the interface, it may not work.

Comment: In my opinion, I think although is possible, it migth be not recommended just because you are introducing extra restrictions to a contract which in the future can be a trouble. I would leave the interfaces as simple as possible. The main purpose of the interfaces is to say "what you do" and not "how you have to do it".
Regards.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I quickly tested it and having `@Async` on an interface will make implementation asynchronous.

If you want to try it yourself: You can easily test this by checking that the values of `Thread.currentThread().getId()` are different (before calling the method and inside the method) or just adding a `Thread.sleep(10000);` in the method expected to be asynchronous.

Also take note the return type must be `void` or `java.util.concurrent.Future`.

Answer (score 12):

Since `@Async` is [defined](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) as

```
@Target(value={TYPE,METHOD})
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Async
```

and `TYPE` [is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html?is-external=true#TYPE)

> Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration

and `METHOD` [is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html?is-external=true#METHOD)

> Method declaration

yes, you can use it on interface methods, too.

Comment: but will it _actually_ make implementation asynchronous too? :)

Comment: yes. it will make all of it's implementations Async